# Keep original node lighting after using a light for another node

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, lighting, scenegraph

I am attempting to give my island more of a "3D" effect, as you cannot see depth in the grass hills.
[image]

My solution was to place the lights in the scene. I have placed a `spot` light above the island, however, the rock underneath is now black/really dark. I would like the rock underneath to be unaffected and stay lit. Here is what I have so far:
[image]

Even when placing an ambient light in the scene editor, it does not help at all with the rock (but slightly brightens the grass by a tiny amount).

*The lighting model I am using is `Blinn`.*

How can I keep my rock like it's original lighting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out to the answer to this very quickly after I made this post, even though I was stuck on this for about a day. It was actually very simple.

All you need to do is go into the original island scene file, and click on the rock and access it's `Material Properties`. Then change the lighting mode from `Blinn` to `Constant`:

[image]

Hope this helps anyone from the future, as there haven't been any other posts I have found about this before! :)

Comment: @Sergio I don’t think it will - because my problem was the shading mode - and yours is a shadow. I’m not on my computer anymore (on my phone), but isn’t there a `created shadow` property you may be able to just untick? I won’t be able to try help until tomorrow, sorry! ):